# org-habit shows no habits

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've posted [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767471/org-capture-and-time-clocking-misbehaving/35344946#35344946) on using Brent Hansen's [amazing org setup](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html). This time around, I'm specifically having a problem with getting org-mode to display my habits.

I had to nuke my emacs and start from scratch recently, so debugging is hard.

I am quite certain that I have `habit` mode enabled since:

1. I have enabled in my `.emacs` (see below)

`;; Enable habit tracking
    (setq org-modules (quote (org-habit)))`

`; position the habit graph on the agenda to the right of the default
    (setq org-habit-graph-column 50)`

`(run-at-time "06:00" 86400 '(lambda () (setq org-habit-show-habits t)))`

2. My capture template for habits, seems to set up to include everything needed:

   `("h" "Habit" entry (file "~/Dropbox/org-new/refile.org")
                  "* NEXT %?\n%U\n%a\nSCHEDULED: %(format-time-string \"%<<%Y-%m-%d %a .+1d/3d>>\")\n:PROPERTIES:\n:STYLE: habit\n:REPEAT_TO_STATE: NEXT\n:END:\n")`
3. I have an additional set of properties in my Top Level Header for habits that reads:

   `* Habits
     :PROPERTIES:
     :LOGGING:  DONE(!)
     :ARCHIVE:  %s_archive::* Habits
     :END:`
4. When I run the agenda, I see `(Org-Agenda Day Ddl Grid Habit Wrap)` in the Mode line

Despite that, my habits do not show up, nor does a habit graph, when I run the agenda. I've trawled everything I can to try and solve this and I'm now at my wit's end. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `:STYLE:` property with the value `habit` to your habits:

```
 ** TODO Shave
    SCHEDULED: <2009-10-17 Sat .+2d/4d>
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-10-15 Thu]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-10-12 Mon]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-10-10 Sat]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-10-04 Sun]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-10-02 Fri]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-09-29 Tue]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-09-25 Fri]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-09-19 Sat]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-09-16 Wed]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2009-09-12 Sat]
    :PROPERTIES:
    :STYLE:    habit
    :LAST_REPEAT: [2009-10-19 Mon 00:36]
    :END:
```

See [Tracking your habits](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html#Tracking-your-habits).

EDIT: While the STYLE:habit property is necessary, that isn't the problem in this case (as discussed in the comments). However, it might well be that the *order* of the elements in the headline is the problem. Running `org-lint` on the following example:

```
* NEXT Exercise
  [2017-07-16 Sun 19:36]
  [[file:~/Dropbox/org-new/todo.org::*Write][Write]]
  SCHEDULED: <2017-07-16 Sun .+1d/2d>
  :PROPERTIES:
    :STYLE: habit
    :REPEAT_TO_STATE: NEXT
  :END:
```

I get

```
 3 low   Link to non-existent local file "~/Dropbox/org-new/todo.org"
 4 low   Misplaced planning info line
 5 high  Incorrect location for PROPERTIES drawer
```

If I reorg the file a bit to this:

```
* NEXT Exercise
  SCHEDULED: <2017-07-16 Sun .+1d/2d>
  :PROPERTIES:
    :STYLE: habit
    :REPEAT_TO_STATE: NEXT
  :END:
 [2017-07-16 Sun 19:36]
 [[file:~/Dropbox/org-new/todo.org::*Write][Write]]
```

then the `high` priority warning disappears. I don't know whether that will make habits work, but I'm willing to bet that it would.

The [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html) states:

> When they are associated with a single entry or with a tree they need to be inserted into a special drawer (see Drawers) with the name PROPERTIES, which has to be located right below a headline, and its planning line (see Deadlines and scheduling) when applicable.

Comment: Hey @Nick, I've done that. If you see my capture template above, it imposes the style. For example, here is one habit with the `:STYLE:` property clearly defined.

`* NEXT Exercise

[2017-07-16 Sun 19:36]

[[file:~/Dropbox/org-new/todo.org::*Write][Write]]

SCHEDULED: <2017-07-16 Sun .+1d/2d>

:PROPERTIES:

:STYLE: habit

:REPEAT_TO_STATE: NEXT

:END:
`

Sorry! The comment box doesn't appear to format newlines right!

Comment: Oops - sorry. I missed that. Where exactly is the first newline in your entry? org 9 has imposed some restrictions on what the structure of an entry should look like. Try running `org-lint` on the file and see if there are any complaints.

Comment: Now that I took another look at your template, I think that it is indeed the structure that is tripping you up (but I haven' tried it out, so take it with the appropriate grain of salt).

Comment: you are absolutely right! Thank you so much. This solves the problem!!